# Objectify - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Embedded Map keys must be of type String/Enum/Key<?> or field must specify @Stringify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have an Objectify entity that's failing to get registered.

Here's a stripped-down version of the class:

```
@com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity
public class Insight {
    @com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id long id;
    public Map<Date, Double> timeseries;
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Embedded Map keys must be of type String/Enum/Key<?> or field must specify @Stringify
```

I believe the error is occurring during Objectify registration:

```
class OfyService {
    static {
        factory().register(Insight.class);
    }
```

It's hard to tell though because there are lots of stack traces because the code is in a static block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objectify doesn't know what to do with a Date as a Map key. Map keys get turned into property names, which must be Strings. So you need to invent a `DateStringifier` class that implements the `Stringifier` interface. It's trivial, but you have some options - you can stringify your dates as millis-since-epoch or as some sort of human-readable format.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Entities#Maps, I must declare the Map in the following way because the Map's key is not a String:

```
@Stringify(com.googlecode.objectify.stringifier.KeyStringifier.class)
public Map<Date, Double> timeseries;
```

Comment: This can't possibly fix the problem - it only delays the problem until you actually try to use it. The `KeyStringifier` stringifies Keys, not Dates.

Comment: Thanks @stickfigure, I thought it had fixed the problem because I got past `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.  But my code still doesn't work.  I'm not sure if the problem I'm seeing is the one you anticipated but I'm trying to query for my object and it's not finding it even though I see it in the datastore.  That might be the result of eventual consistency.  I'm not querying my `Insight` object by the `timeseries` field but by other fields and it just doesn't find the `Insight`.  Is this an example of what you meant by delaying the problem until I try to use it?

Comment: You should get a ClassCastException when you try to save() this field.